All kinds of software problems after updating Kernel / 24.04
I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
this morning I tried to update my system's software. I started by using the GUI (Ubuntu dialog that says "these updates are ready, do you want to install?"
This produced a black screen, and after some time, forced a restart by unplugging my machine. Upon restart, I entered straight into a GRUB prompt.
After some debugging, I realized I had to boot into an older kernel to get into the OS, then I was able to fix the new kernel.
Now that I can boot into the OS, Apps like Brave Browser, Sublime, and BitWarden are all unreesponsive. Google Chrome, VS Code, and Sublime merge seem to be working just fine.
I have no idea what SnapD is, or Apt, or gnome.... i'm guessing one or all of those are corrupt?
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade all report everything is up to date.
attempting to restart snapd results in a hanging terminal (ref: Cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/apps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory)
I then tried to just update to 24.04 (ref: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-22-04-lts-to-ubuntu-24-04-lts/) but terminal stalls when trying to continue the upgrade (sudo do-release-upgrade)
Immediately I need  my Apps like Brave Browser to work. I thought i had installed these apps via the snapd store but i really have no idea why there is snap and gnome and whatever the new one it :/
at some point i will need to upgrade to 24.04...
can anyone help diaglose my software  troubles?

Interactive diagnosis often works best in our sister venue ubuntuforums.org. AskUbuntu's question/answer format assumes that diagnostic information is already available.

Consider fresh installing 24.04. That would not be error prone like this

It seems the problem is that all of my apps inastalled with Snap were broken. i purged my snap installs with this command:
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
I had to rename the Firefox folder because it had some read-only files. After a couple attempts, I was able to empty out my snap folder and reinstall all my apps using apt
